# Output of values() on a QuerySet with ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm currently placing the result of a QuerySet into a JSON string to be used by my js frontend.

Currently this is easy enough using .values() and simplejson:

```
simplejson.dumps(list(Task.objects.filter(list=mylist).values()))
```

I've now added a ManyToMany field in my Task object, would like to have it included in my output without having each Task object repeated for every value of the ManyToMany relationship.

If I just did `Task.objects.filter(list=mylist).values('myManyToManyField', 'someOtherField')`  The output would have a separate object/row for each value of `myManyToManyField`

```
[{'myManyToManyField': 1, 'someOtherField': 'valueOne'}, 
{'myManyToManyField': 2, 'someOtherField': 'valueOne'},
{'myManyToManyField': 1, 'someOtherField': 'valueTwo'}]
```

Is there any way to get this result instead?:

```
[{'myManyToManyField': [1,2], 'someOtherField': 'valueOne'},
{'myManyToManyField': 1, 'someOtherField': 'valueTwo'}]
```

The only solution I have right now is to loop over all the `Task` objects and build the output manually, placing the ManyToMany value within it as desired. Is there a better way to do this? If not - would this be horribly inefficient?

Answer (score 20):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Task.objects.filter(list=mylist).annotate(arr_field=ArrayAgg('myManyToManyField')).values('arr_field', 'someOtherField')
```

Output:

```
[{'arr_field': [1,2], 'someOtherField': 'valueOne'},
 {'arr_field': 1, 'someOtherField': 'valueTwo'}]
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, this definitely should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no other way but iterate over all `Task` objects.

Django's documentation [warns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values) about using 'values()' on 'ManyToManyField'.

It would not be

> horribly inefficient

if you do this way [All the values of the many to many field : Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139923/all-the-values-of-the-many-to-many-field-django)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Django's serializers:

```
import json
from django.core import serializers

json_data = serializers.serialize("json", Task.objects.all())
```

If you want to extract the fields only, do the following:

```
data = [i['fields'] for i in json.loads(json_data)]
```