# All the values of the many to many field : Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now, I want the info of all the books. So, I did:

```
book_info = Book.objects.all().values('title', 'authors__name')
```

And, it gives an output like (for 1 book having 2 authors):

```
[{'title': u'book1', 'authors__name': u'author1'},{'title': u'book1', 'authors__name': u'author2'}]
```

What I wanted was something like:

```
[{'title': u'book1', 'authors': [{'name':u'author1'},{'name':u'author2'}]}]
```

I may have more fields in the author model, so would like to get those fields as well.

Can I do this in a single query?

What can I do to get something like the desired result?

Comment: Not sure such thing available, mostly you need to build such dict yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Django 1.4

Great question, use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
In [3]: [{'name': b.name, 'authors': [a.name for a in b.authors.all()]} for b in Book.objects.prefetch_related('authors')]
(0.000) SELECT "test_app_book"."id", "test_app_book"."name" FROM "test_app_book"; args=()
(0.000) SELECT ("test_app_book_authors"."book_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val", "test_app_author"."id", "test_app_author"."name" FROM "test_app_author" INNER JOIN "test_app_book_authors" ON ("test_app_author"."id" = "test_app_book_authors"."author_id") WHERE "test_app_book_authors"."book_id" IN (1, 2); args=(1, 2)
Out[3]: 
[{'authors': [u'a', u'b'], 'name': u'book'},
 {'authors': [u'b'], 'name': u'test'}]
```

### Django 1.3

prefetch_related was introduced in Django 1.4. For Django 1.3, you need [django-selectreverse](http://code.google.com/p/django-selectreverse):

```
In [19]: [{'name': b.name, 'authors': [a.name for a in b.authors_prefetch]} for b in Book.objects.select_reverse({'authors_prefetch': 'authors'})]
(0.000) SELECT "test_app_book"."id", "test_app_book"."name" FROM "test_app_book"; args=()
(0.001) SELECT (test_app_book_authors.book_id) AS "main_id", "test_app_author"."id", "test_app_author"."name" FROM "test_app_author" INNER JOIN "test_app_book_authors" ON ("test_app_author"."id" = "test_app_book_authors"."author_id") WHERE "test_app_book_authors"."book_id" IN (1, 2); args=(1, 2)
Out[19]: 
[{'authors': [u'a', u'b'], 'name': u'book'},
 {'authors': [u'b'], 'name': u'test'}]
```

Using [django-selectreverse](http://code.google.com/p/django-selectreverse):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = ReverseManager()
```

Comment: that is performing two queries, instead of that do `objects.all` and make your desire dictionary using python, would that not be efficient?

Comment: I don't think so but maybe I don't understand what you mean (sorry)

Comment: Update: use prefetch_related instead of django-selectreverse

Comment: Just to add : `prefetch_related` was introduced in `Django 1.4` onward. So you might want to ensure you are on that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, added instructions for pre 1.4

Comment: Thanks to all for the answer and discussion. My mistake that I did not mention the django version. I am using Django 1.4 on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid doing two queries as in the descriptive answer from @jpic, you could just manually merge your results afterwards. It feels a bit hacky to me, but it works.

```
def merge_values(values):
    grouped_results = itertools.groupby(values, key=lambda value: value['id'])
    merged_values = []
    for k, g in grouped_results:
        groups = list(g)
        merged_value = {}
        for group in groups:
            for key, val in group.iteritems():
                if not merged_value.get(key):
                    merged_value[key] = val
                elif val != merged_value[key]:
                    if isinstance(merged_value[key], list):
                        if val not in merged_value[key]:
                            merged_value[key].append(val)
                    else:
                        old_val = merged_value[key]
                        merged_value[key] = [old_val, val]
        merged_values.append(merged_value)
    return merged_values

book_info = marge_values(Book.objects.all().values('title', 'authors__name'))
```

The merge_values function is take from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pamelafox-coursera/3707015)