# Django values() method with ManyToMany field: it just returns one element

Tags: python, django, performance, export, many-to-many

I need to efficiently export a lot of data from my database to a CSV, and I am having a problem with a ManyToMany field. Let's say my model is `Song` and I am using a ManyToMany field called `Tags`. A `Song` may have several `Tags`, such as 'rock', 'pop', 'sad'...

I would like to do something like:

```
>>> songs_tags = Song.objects.filter(artist_id=5).values('id', 'tags__name')
```

And then I would like to get something like:

```
>>> songs_tags
[{'id': 1L, 'tags__name':['rock', 'pop', 'happy']}, {'id': 2L, 'tags__name': ['metal', 'angry', 'epic']}, ...]
```

However, what I actually get is:

```
>>> songs_tags
[{'id': 1L, 'tags__name': 'rock'}, {'id': 2L, 'tags__name': 'metal'}, ...]
```

Why?

I checked that those elements indeed have more than one tag, but values() only reports one of them, instead of all of them.

Note:

I tried to iterate `for song in Song.objects.filter(artist_id=5)` and to read each `song.tags.all()`. But it is sloow...

I also tried to use `prefetch_related()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). What I did is to iterate `for song in Song.objects.filter(artist_id=5).prefetch_related('tags')` and to read each `song.tags.all()`, but it also was slow. In fact, I didn't notice any difference between iterating `Song.objects.filter(artist_id=5)` and `Song.objects.filter(artist_id=5).prefetch_related('tags')`.

Comment: Possible duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139923/all-the-values-of-the-many-to-many-field-django

Answer (score 1):

You could use [a raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/) to let Postgres fetch the tags and concatenate them into a string to get something like this

*[{'id': 1L, 'tags': 'rock, pop, happy']}, {'id': 2L, 'tags': 'metal, angry, epic']}, ...]*

The raw SQL select would look like this

```
SELECT modulename_song.name AS name,
       string_agg(modulename_tag.name, ', ') AS tags 
FROM modulename_song_tag  
INNER JOIN modulename_song ON song_id=modulename_song.id
INNER JOIN modulename_tag ON tag_id=modulename_tag.id
WHERE song_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM modulename_song 
    WHERE artist_id=5 )
GROUP BY modulename_song.id;
```

assuming you have the following tables built by you Django model

- Song table: `modulename_song`
- Tag table: `modulename_tag`
- ManyToMany relation table: `modulename_song_tag`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately our database is not on Postgress, but in MySQL, and string_agg() is not available. But I like the idea of using a raw SQL query, and I will go on this direction.