# Django values method - related objects in list

Tags: django

Hi help with values () method of queryset. When displaying related fields (Foreign key), the data is repeated, can this data be grouped?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, db_index=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_image', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/models/')
    is_main = models.BooleanField()
```

View code

```
data = Product.objects.all().values('pk', 'title', 'product_image')
```

Example here

This is how it is displayed

```
[
    {'pk': 1, 'title': 'Product 1', 'product_image__image': 'img/models/mod_wpYzlnm.png'}, 
    {'pk': 2, 'title': 'Product 2', 'product_image__image': 'img/models/mod2_wEr0D2q.png'},
    {'pk': 2, 'title': 'Product 2', 'product_image__image': 'img/models/mod_pPQqmjB_we175uR.png'},
    {'pk': 10, 'title': 'Product 3', 'product_image__image': 'img/models/mod_3mTxkb9_z4lKV3l.png'}, 
    {'pk': 10, 'title': 'Product 3', 'product_image__image': 'img/models/heart.png'}
]
```

This is how it should be

```
[
    {'pk': 1, 'title': 'Product 1, 'product_image':[ 
        {'image':'img/models/mod_wpYzlnm.png'}
    ]}, 
    {'pk': 2, 'title': 'Product 2', 'product_image': [
        {'image':'img/models/mod2_wEr0D2q.png'}, 
        {'image':'img/models/mod_pPQqmjB_we175uR.png'}
    ]},
    {'pk': 10, 'title': 'Product 3',  'product_image': [
        {'image':'img/models/mod_3mTxkb9_z4lKV3l.png'}, 
        {'image':'img/models/heart.png'}
    ]}, 
]
```

Comment: When you do what query…?

Comment: data = Product.objects.all().values('pk', 'title', 'product_image')

Comment: I find it quite *odd* that you use a list if there are multiple items, but a string if there is one. This will make the logic of the "reader" more complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output of values() on a QuerySet with ManyToMany fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031563/output-of-values-on-a-queryset-with-manytomany-fields)

Comment: sorry, yes there must be a list `code {'pk': 1, 'title': 'Product 1, 'product_image':[ 
        {'image':'img/models/mod_wpYzlnm.png'}
    ]},`

Comment: Output of values() on a QuerySet with ManyToMany fields – Nicolò Gasparini  does not fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post-process the data with the [**`groupby(…)`** function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of the [**`itertools`** module [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). For the query we should however first order on the `pk`, or at least an item such that the queryset `ProductImage`s is order such that all `ProductImage`s of the same `Product` are next of each other.

We can thus transform this with:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = Product.objects.values('pk', 'title', 'product_image').order_by('pk')

result = [
    {'pk': pk, 'title': title,
    'product_image': [ {'image': pi['product_image__image'] } for pi in pis ] }
    for (pk, title), pis in groupby(data, itemgetter('pk', 'title'))
]
```

for the given sample data, this gives us:

```
[{'pk': 1,
  'product_image': [{'image': 'img/models/mod_wpYzlnm.png'}],
  'title': 'Product 1'},
 {'pk': 2,
  'product_image': [{'image': 'img/models/mod2_wEr0D2q.png'},
                    {'image': 'img/models/mod_pPQqmjB_we175uR.png'}],
  'title': 'Product 2'},
 {'pk': 10,
  'product_image': [{'image': 'img/models/mod_3mTxkb9_z4lKV3l.png'},
                    {'image': 'img/models/heart.png'}],
  'title': 'Product 3'}]
```